# can't change the UILabel.titleLabel.text

Tags: ios

Strange issue where I'm trying to set the titleLabel.text but it won't change from the default title text.  I've stepped through it in the debugger and examined the taskTitle value which is correctly the new value but the titleButton.titleLabel.text property doesn't seem to take the value assignment.

```
- (void)setChallengeTitle:(NSString *)taskTitle
{
    titleButton.titleLabel.text = taskTitle;
    titleButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham Bold" size:18];



    CGSize stringsize = [taskTitle sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham Bold" size:18]];
    //I have to add a little bit since it doesn't seem to calculate the size of gotham correctly
    int buttonWidth = stringsize.width + 20;
    if (buttonWidth > 320)
        buttonWidth = 320;

    [titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake( (320 - buttonWidth)/2 ,10, buttonWidth, 40)];
}
```

Comment: How about `titleButton` – might it be nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the text of the `UIButton` through the methods?

Try:

`[titleButton setTitle:taskTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

`UIControlStateNormal` will set the title for all states.

Comment: Awesome! `UIButton`s are quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows the default text, it probably means that it is not properly connected as an IBOutlet.

Check your linking in the interface builder.

Hope it helps..

Comment: It's properly connected and I am able to update it when I call update on it from a different place.  Let me track down what the differences are and I will post.